# let my table be in the center of the page

Tags: tables

```
\begin{tabular}{ |p{4.5cm}|p{6cm}|p{4.5cm}|  }
\hline
\multicolumn{3}{|c|}{Table X: Initial Examples of Communications Through Intelligent Surface} \\
\hline
 Scheme & Architecture & Functionality \\
\hline
Intelligent wall & Active frequency selective surfaces with PIN diodes & Fully transparent reflecting surfaces\\
Spatial microwave modulators & Binary phase state tunable meta-surfaces & Shaping complex microwave fields\\
Coding meta-materials & Meta-surfaces with binary elements (0 or $\pi$ phases) & Reconfigurable scattering patterns\\
Programmable meta-surface & Meta-surfaces with PIN diode-equipped cells & Reconfigurable phase, polarization,
and scattering\\
Reconfigurable reflect-arrays & Reflect-arrays with tunable (varactor-tuned) resonators & Adjustable reflection phase\\
Large intelligent surface & Active contiguous surface for transmission and reception & Gains compared to massive MIMO   \\
Software-controlled hypersurface & Meta-surfaces equipped with IoT gateways & Wave absorption, polarization,
and steering\\
\hline
\end{tabular}\\
```

Comment: Have you tried putting your table in a `table` environment and then adding the `\centering` command?

Comment: No, the table still in the right side.